# nginx + wordpress in /wordpress subdir

Tags: php, nginx, wordpress

I installed nginx and would like to setup wordpress as a final step.
I followed many howtos but am unable to get it working.

The setup is fairly straightforward, the root dir of the webserver is /data/Sites/nkr1pt.homelinux.net. In that root dir I created a symlink to the wordpress folder in /usr/local/wordpress, so in fact all wordpress files can be accessed at /data/Sites/nkr1pt.homelinux.net/wordpress. Permissions are ok.

The plan is to get wordpress working at http://sirius/wordpress, the server's name is sirius.
spawn-fcgi is running and listening on port 7777.

Here you can see the relevant config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
listen       8080;
    server_name  sirius;

root /data/Sites/nkr1pt.homelinux.net;
passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_base_uri /redmine;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

location ^~ /data {
   root /data/Sites/nkr1pt.homelinux.net;
   autoindex on;
   auth_basic "Restricted";
   auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
}

    location ^~ /dump {
        root   /data/Sites/nkr1pt.homelinux.net;
        autoindex on;
    }

location ^~ /wordpress {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:7777
    location ~ \.php$ {
    #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/wordpress)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass   localhost:7777;
        #fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    #index     index.php;
    }
```

please note that redmine, and the locations dump and data are working perfectly, it is only wordpress that I cannot get to work.

Can you please help me to the correct wordpress configuration in nginx?
All help is much appreciated!

Comment: Remeber that Igor Sysoev (nginx author) strongly disagree with running apps on nginx. He is very taxative that nginx is to be used as a proxy between the outside and app servers.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you include "fastcgi_params" in your nginx.conf *after* setting:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

If fastcgi_params overrides SCRIPT_FILENAME with something different, the previous line will be ignored and Wordpress won't work. I suggest that you invert the order of those two lines, like this:

```
include        fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Comment: Calling index.php without any args is perfectly fine. WordPress supports this with no problem; it gets the args out of the FastCGI `REQUEST_URI` and `QUERY_STRING` parameters when called via FastCGI. The rest of your advice is sound; `fastcgi_params` should be `include`d before overriding things that appear in it.

Comment: You are right, I tested without args and it works as well. Edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen the main thing to get wordpress working is to translate the mod_rewrite rules into nginx format. The format is:

```
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```

You are also missing

```
root /path/to/wordpress
```

In that subsection.

Otherwise, is there a particular error you are seeing? What do the error logs show?

Comment: I added the rewrite and root parts in location ~ \.php$
error.log gives no errors, when i try to load http://sirius/wordpress in the browser it shows a popup to download a BIN file; file content is php source from wordpress:

define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./wp-blog-header.php');

Comment: with editing and trying the nginx config file I also noticed 'input file is not specified' which seems to come from wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Use a server level rewrite. You should adjust all other locations. Oh and BTW, your setup is insecure. You should use a nested location or `fastcgi_split_path_info`. You can check my [WP config](https://github.com/perusio/wordpress-nginx) on github for a nested location approach.

Anyway here's your request answered:

```
 rewrite ^ http://$host/wordpress$request_uri? permanent;
```